# finding rf 175 Mhz harmonic source

Tags: rf, fcc, spectrum-analyzer

I have a device that I am pre testing to find possible issues with unintentional rf radation.  The processor is a pic32 running at 80MHz, and is connected to a ti dp83848 ethernet phy in mii mode using a 25MHz crystal.

I see peaks at 75MHz, 150, and 175.  I am a little unclear where these harmonics could be originating.  Could I get this activity from a 25MHz crystal, all the way up to 175?  The peaks are pretty much spot on, at least according to the rigol dsa815.

Addition:  I have done more testing here, I see most of these harmonics are generated in the phy area, and between the phy and jack.  I have some traces that run in an internal layer that go through that area and come out right at the indicator switch legs, and they are picking up these harmonics.  Its a little unclear to me whether or not these are over the limit, I may just have to test and see.  My understanding is that near field probes pick up a signal whether or not there is an unintentional antenna or slot big enough to pass the signal.  I suspect most ethernet devices have some harmonics in this range.  The pic32 ethernet starter has similar results.

I may have just have to pay the test house for this education.
[image: Button/slot side]

[image: Processor and phy]

Comment: "mHz" indicates 1/1000 of 1 Hz. "MHz" indicates 1000000 Hz.

Comment: It's also a capital "H" in Hz as per @ThePhoton's comment. Where are you measuring the 175MHz and with what equipment?

Comment: I am measuring it using the large (1" loop) beehive probe, 20db preamp, and rigol dsa815.  Demodulation of the signal shows the same noise on the other peaks.  I am measuring it through slots and button holes in the enclosure, with the probe laid flat over the slots/holes.  The board is a 6 layer SGSSPS manhattan routing, is on standoffs and directly behind the buttons.

Comment: Willy's answer as well as he disappeared.  I guess its a mystery of stackexchange.  One thing of note, I don't see any of these harmonics leaving on the ethernet cable, neither by loop probe, or homemade current probe, per emc blog instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got a 25 MHz Square wave oscillator, then it's not surprising to see harmonics up to  the 7th. If it's a sine wave oscillator, I suspect your Ethernet Phy is doing some squaring up.

Comment: It is a 25Mhz crystal driven by the phy.  I hadn't thought of the squaring possibility, which could be more in the line of the wrong load caps, perhaps.

Comment: I have finally got around to more testing, changed caps, tested, etc, it is not due to this.  The is a crystal oscillator anyway, not square.

Comment: @ErikFriesen - it is almost certainly due to this, and the edge-aligned switching currents which result, though which specific part of the circuit driven by this clock is radiating may take a while to discover.  If you really don't believe it, add a variable capacitor  across one of the crystal loading caps and tune a beat frequency oscillator (CW/SSB) type receiver to the 175 MHz spur to produce an audible tone.  Turn the capacitor to "pull" the crystal frequency a few 10s-100s of Hz and you will probably hear that spur move (7 times as far).

Comment: Yes, it squares by feature of the fact that its internal clock starts at 25mhz, but if it was an crystal cap problem, then would not the strongest harmonics be at the crystal?  There are other locations where a square 25mhz clock is going on, but not where I can do much about it, like the RXclk on the phy.  Changing the load caps from 18pf to 33pf made no noticeable difference.

Comment: I could answer my own question, but I won't, since this led to the answer.  The fcc test showed some harmonics of 25 all the way up to 300mhz, but well below the part b limits.